# ReactJS - What is the standard method of initializing jquery plugin in a react class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, reactjs

I am using this plugin - [bootstrap-dropselect](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?DcqjqoK6)

I have written initDropSelect function to initialize this plugin but I am not sure where to call this function as I would like to append some html to the DOM as soon as route is loaded. I am getting data from two different ajax calls. That data has to be compared and manipulated to append that html to the DOM(Code below 'Append to DOM' comment).

```
let UserPanel = React.createClass({

  mixins: [LinkedStateMixin],

  getStateFromStores: function() {
    var users = UserStore.getAll();

    // Some more code
    return {
      users: users
      // Other properties
    };
  }
  componentDidMount: function() {
    UserStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange: function() {
    this.setState(this.getStateFromStores());
  },


  initDropSelect: function() {
    var _self = this;
    var dropSelect = $('#dropselect-demo1').dropselect({
      filter: {
        show: true,
        placeholder: 'Search for an item'
      },
      multiselect: true,
      onselect: function(e, item) {

      },
      onunselect: function(e, item) {

      },
      onclear: function(e) {

      }
    });

    // Append to DOM

    if(this.state.tagsList.length > 0) {
      if(this.state.newLoan.data.tags.length > 0) {
        // Getting data from two different resources
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Please help me in deciding where to call initDropSelect to manipulate data from multiple async requests and append that data to DOM.

P.S. I am using react router so there are two scenarios. First I may come to this route from other route or I can straightaway reload the current page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is for your render method to return something like a `<div />` that you will then use to mount the jQuery component into. Once mounted, `this` will point to the DOM element that you would normally pass to jQuery.

Since jQuery will be handling the rendering, you then want to always return false from `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This will prevent React from thrashing your jQuery component.

You can then use `componentDidMount()` to initialize your jQuery component and `componentWillReceiveProps()` to update/re-render it when new data is passed in.